# Dynamic Websockets in a Web App

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, spring-websocket

**Good afternoon :)**,

I was hoping somebody could give a bit of guidance and direction regarding Websockets in my particular context. I am working on a webapp in which registered users can create a chat room/live events (or however you wish to call it), other users should be able to join given a specific room id. The user who created can also close the current connection forbidding any further connections. Obviously there needs to be capability for more than one event occurring simultaneously. I have read a lot of examples online and most of them do not share any idea of concurrent sockets/rooms, or maybe I am missing the fundamental concepts (very possible).

**Thanks :-)**, I am new to websockets and any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

If You are new in websocket Programmer.

> You need to See this [zaneacademy playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSM8fkP9ppPo6cKmykJuVtTJzzHxDqHaJ) and [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html) give
>   complete practical knowledge about how to make websocket in netbeans
>   step by step.
>
> And You just need to make chatroom in websocket [go to here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BikL52HYaZg&list=PLSM8fkP9ppPo6cKmykJuVtTJzzHxDqHaJ&index=2)